# Consul configuration on multiple node

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos, dig, consul

In consul documentation it says that the service configuration files should be stored in `/etc/consul.d/` directory.

I am running a 3 nodes cluster, do I have to cpy the consul.d on each node or will the sync will be done inside the cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your service configuration files only on that node where it's really started, 'cause agent  [endpoints are used to interact with the local Consul agent](https://consul.io/docs/agent/http/agent.html) only. After that it will  synchronized with the cluster automatically.

So, if you have service started on node1, you should store config file for this service only in node1 `/etc/consul.d/` directory.